# Are front load washers expected to filter out lint and pet hair?

Tags: washing-machine, filter, water-filtration

I've had my LG VC4 for a couple of years already, and never had issues with its functioning. However, about a year or so ago we noticed the exit pipe in the wall got clogged, since the washer started leaking water all over the laundry. I did some "investigation" and... you already know it got clogged with lint because of the question title lol

This is the type of "filter" this model has; given the size of the holes, it's made to get small pieces of cloth or lines, coins, keys, stuff like that - it's definitely not a lint filter.

[image: VC4 filter which doesn't filter lint]

My lifetime experience was with top-load machines, which always(?) had some sort of lint filter at the top of the water line or on the center of the drum. So I'm quite shocked when I tried to contact LG multiple times, and they either didn't get it and suggested me to get (pay for) a support visit, or simply said "your LG washer is expected to leave lint through the hose, given it's a drain hose (!!!), it's not a defect it's a characteristic of it".

So, what gives? Could the house pipe be too narrow? It's enough for the drain hose to fit in... Or is it *really* expected to not have a lint filter at all with front-load washers?

> I'm not exactly sure why this was preemptively closed; unfortunately I have nothing to add to the edit, except mention [the rules](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) which seem to apply fine to my question, specifically:
>
> *"We welcome these topics: [...]*
>
> - *Identifying the source or cause of a problem within your home.*
> - *Installation, maintenance, and repair of major appliances.*

Comment: I'm glad the dictators took a while to close my question - no one ever explained the reason it is off-topic, I've given reasons for it NOT to be, but gladly the responses given were right on point and very informative (before these people randomly burning my question, of course).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Note that this answer is about what you **should** do about washing machine lint. It doesn't take care of the existing problem, which appears to be a machine-specific failure (a.k.a., it broke).*

---

Every dryer I have ever used had a lint filter. That's because otherwise the lint would end up getting stuck along the exhaust vent (some inevitably does anyway, which needs cleaning to prevent fires).

No washer I have ever used had a lint filter. That's because lint *can* go safely down the drain. Lint down the drain won't cause a fire.

However, lint down a drain, particularly if the same drain services a kitchen (grease, food particles, etc.) and/or bathrooms (soap scum, hair) can, over time, get clogged up. I've had every type of clog in my drains (food, hair, lint, roots, and more) and I dread the call of "the sink (or bathtub, etc.) is draining slowly again" and even worse "the floor drain backed up again". An ounce of prevention is worth a pound of cure. I highly recommend putting a lint trap over the drain hose. I use something like [these from Amazon](https://amzn.to/3PgQ5oB):

[image: lint trap]

In my area they are available at hardware stores and even at grocery stores. Very effective.

Comment: Awesome product! I should've mentioned I'm talking from Brazil, and here it's not common to have a separate dryer - you either have a double-functioning device, or just the washer. Your answer explains a lot, makes a lot of sense to me - especially the part on the dreaded "drain backing up again" -, and seems quite helpful!
I just want to stress the machine isn't broke, support directly said it doesn't seem designed to filter lint, just like you mentioned about your washers.
I'll let the question sit for a couple of days before accepting your answer, but thanks!!

Comment: For a foreigner like me, and maybe for others ending up here, I found pretty much the [same lint trap on AliExpress](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005005613458015.html)

Answer (score 2):

A "lint" filter in the pump discharge would get blocked very quickly. Something's wrong with your drain piping, or you are abusing it, if the discharge from a clothes washer can clog it up.  None of the numerous (top-loading) clothes washers I've used had any kind of filter in them, aside from the smallish perforations in the inner drum wall.

Comment: Funny to know you never had a top loader with lint filter; it seems common around here in Brazil - I guess this _might_ shed a light on the issue, given the LG is obviously a product designed outside of the country... But yeah, a good filter on the pump would be terrible - I only saw it inside the drum, working passively.